# Gurobi multi objectives

Tags: c#, gurobi

i am a bit confused on how i can use multiple objective functions in Gurobi. I found [this](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/examples/multiobj_cs_cs.html) but dont realy understand how i can implement multiple objective functions with this.

Usually i set something like a GRBLinExpr as Objective. But there i cant set ObjN as in the example. Another thing is that i want to minimize and maximize some objectives.

Here is a simple example (dose not work):

```
GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv();
GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env);

var x = model.AddVar(0, 10, 0, GRB.INTEGER, "");
var y = model.AddVar(0, 10, 0, GRB.INTEGER, "");
var z = model.AddVar(0, 10, 0, GRB.INTEGER, "");

var expr1 = new GRBLinExpr();
expr1.AddTerm(1, x);
expr1.AddTerm(1, y);
expr1.AddTerm(1, z);

model.AddConstr(expr1 >= 5, "");


var expr2 = new GRBLinExpr();
expr2.AddTerm(1,z);

model.NumObj = 3; // there are 3 Objectives
model.Parameters.ObjNumber = 1;
model.ObjNWeight = 1;
model.ObjNPriority = 2;
model.ObjNName = "MinSum";
// i need to set this somehow ...
model.SetObjective(expr2, GRB.MAXIMIZE); 


model.Parameters.ObjNumber = 2;
model.ObjNWeight = 1;
model.ObjNPriority = 1;
model.ObjNName = "MaxZ";
// i need to set this somehow ...
model.SetObjective(expr1, GRB.MINIMIZE); // overwrites first objective

model.Optimize();
Console.WriteLine($"x={x.X} y={y.X} z={z.X}");
```

so the solution for this code should be x=0, y=0, Z=10 for example

how can i achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 7.5, the method GRBModel.SetObjectiveN() [supports multiple objectives](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/specifying_multiple_object.html).  If you use GRBModel.SetObjectiveN(), your code should work with version 7.5, though you should fix the following errors:

1. `model.NumObj` should be 2
2. `model.Parameters.ObjNumber` should be 0 and 1, respectively

Comment: thank you i have version 7.0 so i need to upgrade my version